# How to change priority in math order(asterisk)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, math

I want users to input math formula in my system. How can convert case1 formula to case2 formula using Python? In another word, I would like to change math order specifically for double asterisks.

```
#case1
3*2**3**2*5
>>>7680

#case2
3*(2**3)**2*5
>>>960
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You did change the math order...

Comment: You want exponentiation to bind more tightly than multiplication?  You'll have to write code that goes through and inserts parentheses before your pass it to your evaluating function.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this not something that Python supports, but really, why would you want to? Modifying BIDMAS or PEMDAS (depending on your location), would not only give you incorrect answers, but also confuse the hell out of any devs looking at the code.

Just use brackets like in Case 2, it's what they're for.

Comment: Correction, OP is not changing different operator precedence, but rather stacked exponentiation order. It would have been clearer, if the example was `2**3**2` vs. `(2**3)**2` -- in both cases it is the same operator -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Special_cases

Comment: Even the associativity is pretty much set as standard, `x**y**z` should always be right associative so it is `x ** (y ** z)`. This is needed for things like the normal distribution where you have a formula like `e ** (-t ** 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If users are supposed to enter formulas into your program, I would suggest keeping it as is. The reason is that exponentiation in mathematics is [right-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), meaning the execution goes from the top level down. For example: `a**b**c = a**(b**c)`, by convention.

There are some programs that use bottom-up resolution of the stacked exponentiation -- MS Excel and LibreOffice are some of them, however, it is against the regular convention, and always confused the hell out of me.

If you would like to override this behavior, and still be mathematically correct, you have to use brackets.

You can always declare your own power method that would resolve the way you want it -- something like `numpy.pow()`. You could overload the built-in, but that's too much hastle.

[Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Special_cases)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example to achieve this using `re` as:

```
expression = '3*2**3**2*5'
asterisk_exprs = re.findall(r"\d+\*\*\d+", expression) # List of all expressions matching the criterion 
for expr in asterisk_exprs:
    expression = expression.replace(expr, "({})".format(expr)) # Replace the expression with required expression

# Value of variable 'expression': '3*(2**3)**2*5'
```

In order to evaluate the mathematical value of `str` expression, use `eval` as:

```
>>> eval(expression) 
960
```

Comment: Your output is syntactically invalid.  Edit: was

Comment: Updated the answer.